# Insert on a select statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a insert off a select statement... If this is possible? mySQL

```
Insert into listeners (TotalSessionTime) = (SELECT TIMEDIFF(StopTime, StartTime) from listeners where ID = 48);
```

Comment: INSERT INTO listeners (TotalSessionTime)
    SELECT (timediff(StopTime, StartTime))
    FROM listeners
    WHERE ID = 48

Also tried this ---- it runs but TotalSessionTime doesn't change.

Comment: Why would it? It's an INSERT, not an UPDATE

Comment: The question is valid; I'd need to write it to a different table.. but still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are very close

```
Insert into listeners (TotalSessionTime)
   SELECT TIMEDIFF(StopTime, StartTime) from listeners where ID = 48;
```

Comment: I'll need to change this to write to a different table... but thanks.